Не работает Port Forwarding в Ubuntu с UFW
Хочу оставить открытым во внешний мир только 443 порт, а все с него переводить на локальный 8443, который должен быть закрыт для внешнего мира.
В /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf раскомментировал net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
В /etc/ufw/before.rules добавил
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
COMMIT

Открыл ufw allow 443/tcp, потом конечно systemctl restart ufw и Forwarding с 443 не работает. Но, если открыть еще и ufw allow 8443/tcp, то Forwarding сразу начинает работать. Если сделать только  sudo ufw allow in on lo to any port 8443, то тоже работать не будет.
Пробовал и через iptables sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443, но если закрыть в ufw 8443 для внешки, то Forwarding перестает работать.

У меня Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.10.4-x64v3-xanmod1 x86_64)

Скорее всего что-то прописал в настройках ядра файл sysctl.conf. Как в папке /etc/ так и /etc/ufw/...

Все что прописал, указал в вопросе. В /etc/sysctl.conf это net.ipv4.ip_forward=1, в /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf net/ipv4/ip_forward=1 еще в нем же уже по умолчанию прописано было:
net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_redirects=0
net/ipv4/conf/default/accept_redirects=0
net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_redirects=0
net/ipv6/conf/default/accept_redirects=0
net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=1
net/ipv4/icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses=1
net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all=0
net/ipv4/conf/all/log_martians=0
net/ipv4/conf/default/log_martians=0
